# Microsoft SQL Server - Failed attached database version issue

Tags: sql-server

I have issue to attach database. So, my team has a database and I want to install the database into my own machine. I asked my team to detach the database, so the .mdf and log files can be sent to me. When I want to attached the database, the error occured

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Attach database failed for Server 'MyMachine\SQLEXPRESS'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=14.0.17277.0+((SSMS_Rel_17_4).180625-0100)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Attach+database+Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

The database 'Database_Name' cannot be opened because it is version 869. This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database 'Database_Name'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 948)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=948&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

I have tried to download the patch, from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15, is that the right solution? I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17 Express Edition

Thanks

Comment: Please ensure SQL server from where .mdf file is taken and the destination where you are attaching the MDF file has the same SQL server version.

Comment: It doesn't matter what SSMS version you have installed. The error is because you are trying to attach to a SQL Server 2014 instance. Install SQL Server 2017/2019 Express or Developer edition.